# Parse stderr inline alongside stdout using popen

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **What specific syntax needed to be changed in the Python3 code below in order for text output from `stderr` to be handled conditionally as it is output?**

When the function below is run, the program is able to `Do something` whenever `someString` is found in a line of `stdout` output during runtime.

The problem is that `stderr` is also printed to the command line, but `stderr` output is not handled through any string parsing code like you see below for `stdout`.

```
def runCommand(commandToRun, workingDir ):
  proc = subprocess.Popen( commandToRun,cwd=workingDir,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
  while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if line:
      thetext=line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n')
      decodedline=ansi_escape.sub('', thetext)
      print(decodedline)
      if "someString" in decodedline:
        print("Do something!")
    else:
      break
```

Comment: how about `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` and later `proc.stderr.readline()` ?

Comment: eventually redirect `stderr=subprocess.STOUT` and you should have all in `proc.stdout.readline()`

Comment: @furas How should your suggestion be integrated with the `while True` block?

Comment: if you use `stderr=subprocess.STOUT` in `popen()` then you don't have to change `while True` because you should get all in `line = proc.stdout.readline()`. But if you use `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` then you would need `errline = proc.stderr.readline()` but problem is that `readline()` can block code and would need some non-blocking method to check `readline()` or it may need `select.select()` to test if there are new data to read and then use `readline()`

Comment: typo - it has to be `STDOUT` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two solutions:

1. redirect `stderr` to `stdout` using `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` in `Popen` and then you can get all in `proc.stdout`.
   See `main-redirect.py` belowe.
2. use `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` to get it in `proc.sterr` - so you can use different methods to work with `stdout` or `stderr` - but `readline()` blocks code so it needs `select.select()` to check if there are new data in `stdout` or `stderr` before running `readline()`. But I'm not sure if `select` works on Windows - I checked it only on Linux.
   See `main-select.py` belowe.

---

`test.py` - it generates text on `stdout` and `stderr` which I will catch in other scripts.

```
import sys
import time

i = 0
for _ in range(10):
    i += 1
    #sys.stdout.write('stdout {}\n'.format(i))
    #sys.stdout.flush()
    print('stdout {}'.format(i), file=sys.stdout, flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    
    i += 1
    #sys.stderr.write('STDERR {}\n'.format(i))
    #sys.stderr.flush()
    print('STDERR {}'.format(i), file=sys.stderr, flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

`main-redirect.py`

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('python3 test.py', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)

while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    if line:
        print('STDOUT >>>', line.decode(), end='')
    else:
        break
```

`main-select.py`

```
import subprocess
import select

p = subprocess.Popen('python3 test.py', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

while True:
    # check if there are new data to read
    result = select.select([p.stdout, p.stderr], [], [])
    
    if p.stdout in result[0]:
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        if line:
            print('STDOUT >>>', line.decode(), end='')
        else:
            break

    if p.stderr in result[0]:
        line = p.stderr.readline()
        if line:
            print('STDERR >>>', line.decode(), end='')
        else:
            break
```

---

Doc: [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html), [select](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html)